# Connecting to local docker-compose container Windows 10

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

Very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124711/why-cant-i-connect-to-my-local-docker-compose-container-on-windows-10) question, I cannot connect to my local docker-compose container from my browser (Firefox) on Windows 10 and have been troubleshooting for some time, but I cannot seem to find the issue.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    frontend:
        container_name: frontend
        build: ./frontend
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        working_dir: /home/node/app/
        environment:
            DEVELOPMENT: "yes"
        stdin_open: true
        volumes:
          - ./frontend:/home/node/app/
        command: bash -c "npm start & npm run build"
    my_app_django:
        container_name: my_app_django
        build: ./backend/
        environment:
        SECRET_KEY: "... not included ..."
        command: ["./rundjango.sh"]
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/code
            - media_volume:/code/media
            - static_volume:/code/static
        expose:
            - "443"
    my_app_nginx:
        container_name: my_app_nginx
        image: nginx:1.17.2-alpine
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/nginx.dev.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
          - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
          - ./frontend:/home/app/frontend/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
          - my_app_django
volumes:
    static_volume: 
    media_volume:
```

I can start the containers with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` and there are no errors when I check the logs with `docker logs my_app_django` or `docker logs my_app_nginx`. Additionally, doing `docker ps` shows all the containers running as they should.

The odd part about this issue is that on Linux, everything runs without issue and I can find my app on localhost at port 80. The only thing I do differently when I am on Windows is that I run a `dos2unix` on my .sh files to ensure that they run properly. If I omit this step, then I get many errors which leads me to believe that I have to do this.

If anyone could give guidance/advice as to what may I be doing incorrectly or missing altogether, I would be truly grateful. I am also happy to provide more details, just let me know. Thank you!

EDIT #1: As timur suggested, I did a `docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx` and here was the output:

```
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
bf5952930446: Pull complete
ba755a256dfe: Pull complete
c57dd87d0b93: Pull complete
d7fbf29df889: Pull complete
1f1070938ccd: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:36b74457bccb56fbf8b05f79c85569501b721d4db813b684391d63e02287c0b2
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
19b56a66955145e4f59eefff57340b4affe5f7e0d82ad013742a60b479687c40
C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint naughty_hoover (8c7b2fa4aef964899c366e1897e38727bb7e4c38431875c5cb8456567005f368): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.
```

This might be the cause of the error but I don't really understand what needs to be done at this point.

EDIT #2: As requested, here are my Dockerfiles (one for backend, one for frontend)

Backend Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  imagemagick libxmlsec1-dev pkg-config
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code
```

Frontend Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /home/node/app/
COPY . /home/node/app/
RUN npm install -g react-scripts
RUN npm install
```

EDIT #3: When I do `docker ps`, this is what I get:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
0da02ad8d746        nginx:1.17.2-alpine        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp       my_app_nginx
070291de8362        my_app_frontend            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   frontend
2fcf551ce3fa        my_app_django              "./rundjango.sh"         12 days ago         Up About an hour    443/tcp                  my_app_django
```

Comment: are you using Docker Toolbox (the stack backed by VirtualBox) by any chance?

Comment: Yes! I am doing all this via Docker Toolbox and running everything in the Docker Quickstart Terminal

Comment: Then you likely need to `docker-machine ip default` (which will likely show you `192.168.99.100`) and use that ip instead of `localhost`

Comment: are you sure that all your containers are running ? the command `"npm start & npm run build"` will not work you missed one &

Comment: Please add also the Dockerfiles

Comment: @timur, I do get 192.168.99.100 as my default ip, but I still cannot see my app when I go to 192.168.99.100:80 on my browser

Comment: @LinPy when I do a `docker ps`, all my apps appear here and seem to be running correctly. I also changed added another `&` to my command and the results were the same

Comment: Do you get the same error or it's just blank? Can you try something simple like `docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx`? I suspect your host volume mappings would also have to change  because of Virtual box not being so tightly integrated

Comment: Also might be worth checking your VirtualBox networking setup. It's kinda hard to tell you what to look for but knowing docker machine is just a simple VM might point you somewhere

Comment: @timur i edited my question after running the command you suggested. Also, when you say to check my VirtualBox setup, what specifically do you mean?

Comment: Something (I suspect your other container from  docker-compose) on your docker machine already uses port 80. Run `docker ps` to confirm. As to what settings to check, i think your setup if fine as it appears that your machine is connected and it can pull images.

Comment: @timur I added the output of `docker ps` to my question.

Comment: so container `0da02ad8d746` runs and occupies port 80. either stop it or try `docker run -p 81:80 -d nginx` - just see if `http://192.168.99.100:81` would respond at all

Comment: I first tried stopping the container, but the problem persisted. So then I tried your other command, and i was able to get nginx to run on port 81.

Comment: So then it's the issue with your container. As I hinted above, very likely to do with mounting host volumes onto container. Docker toolbox requires passing different paths relative to docker machine itself.

Comment: @timur are there any links/guidance as to how to setup these paths?

Comment: @timur thank you for your help! No rush with the answer. I really hope it works cuz you deserve the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we established you use [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) that is backed by VirtualBox rather than *default* `Hyper-V` Docker for Windows. In this case you might think of it as a VBox VM that actually runs Docker - so all volume mounts and port mappings apply to **docker machine VM**, not your host. And management tools (i.e. Docker terminal and `docker-compose`) actually run on **your host OS** through [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

---

Due to this, you don't get binding ports on `localhost` by default (but you can achieve this by [editing VM properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45822356/12339804) in [VirtualBox manually](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/020_tip_using_docker_containers_as_localhost_on_mac_and_windows.html) if you so desire - I just googled the second link for some picture tutorials). Suprisingly, the official documentation on this particular topic is pretty scarce - you can get a hint by [looking at their examples](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#how-to-uninstall-toolbox) though.

#### So in your case, the correct url should be `http://192.168.99.100`

---

Another thing that is different between these two solutions is volume mounts. And again, [documentation sorta hints](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories) at what it should be but I can't point you a more explicit source. As you have probably noticed the terminal you use for all your docker interactions encodes paths a bit differently (I presume because of that [MinGW layer](http://mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)) and converted paths get sent off to docker-machine - because it's Linux and would not handle windows-style paths anyway.

From here I see a couple of avenues for you to explore:

#### Run your project from `C:\Users\...\MyProject`

As the [documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories), you get `c:\Users` mounted into `/c/Users` by default. So theoretically, if you run your `docker-compose` from your user home folder - paths should automagically align - but since you are having this issue - you are probably running it from somewhere else.

#### Create another share

You also can [create your own mounting mount in Virtual Box](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/#optional-add-shared-directories). Run `pwd` in your terminal and note where project root is. Then  use Virtual Vox UI and create a path that would make it align with your directory tree (for example, `D:\MyProject\` should become `/d/MyProject`.

Hopefully this will not require you to change your `docker-compose.yml` either

#### Alternatively, switch to Hyper-V Docker Desktop - and these particular issues will go away.

Bear in mind, that Hyper-V will not coexist with VirtualBox. So this option might not be available to you if you need VBox for something else.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. I have been working to get something working; I have done an extraordinary amount of reading about this, and your ideas came up in my search. For whatever reason though, I can't seem to get it to work on Docker Toolbox, so I am gonna get Windows 10 Pro so I can use Hyper-V Desktop. Thanks for your help!